# Using Fermat's little theorem to prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-3} (-1)^{i}a^{n-2-i}b^{i+1} = 1 + $ multiple of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Using Fermat's little theorem, prove that
>
> $$ a^{n-2}b - a^{n-3}b^2 + a^{n-4}b^4 - \ldots + ab^{n-2} = 1 + M(n) $$
>
> if $n$ is prime and doesn't divide $a$, $b$ or $a+b$ and $M(n)$ means a multiple of n.

I don't know what to do after getting the closed form of the sum.

Hints please!

Comment: It woul help if you actually wrote down and told us what you found as the closed form of the sum. The solution is close once you have the right closed form.

Comment: I had got the same thing that Glen O has written, just that I hadn't transfered $a + b$ to the LHS. The main reason I couldn't solve the problem was my inexperience with Fermat's theorem. I hadn't really worked any problems with it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$
(a+b)\left(a^{n-2}b - a^{n-3}b^2 + a^{n-4}b^4 - ... + ab^{n-2}\right) = a^{n-1}b+ab^{n-1}
$$
Now evaluate mod $n$ using Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Actually I was a bit unfamiliar with the $mod$ notation. But then seeing that you are doing the same thing I did, I just converted the $mod$ notation into the notation used in Euclid's lemma and then it worked.